# "Uninitialized string offset" fix without php native function

Tags: php

I have a code below which checks and output each character in a $string variable

```
$string = "long string";
for($i=0; $string[$i] !== ""; $i++) {
    echo $string[$i]."<br>";
}
```

this code will have a notice that says

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 11

I know the problem because there is no $string[11].

how can I fix this without using native php functions like empty(), is_null() or any other functions?

Comment: I don't think its possible without any native php functions

Comment: You can suppress the error messages by setting ini_set('display_errors', 0); before your code.

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar well yes I can try that but that is not actually solving the problem, it is only hiding error.

Comment: I don't think there is any other possible way.